# Buffer local export options in org-html-export

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I'm creating a simple web page with org-mode and I use org-html-postamble to do a timestamp and copyright notice for my project, as described [here](http://orgmode.org/org.html#Project-alist).  Now I would like to disable the postamble for only one of the source files.  Can I do this with buffer local options as explained here: http://orgmode.org/manual/Export-settings.html ?

I tried

```
#+ORG_HTML_POSTAMBLE: nil
```

to no avail.

Edit: I updated the question after more research showed why it would not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to the question is "no".  File local variables don't take precedence over what is defined in the project alist.  Quoting from the variable description of `org-html-postamble`:

```
Setting :html-postamble in publishing projects will take precedence over this variable.
```

My solution is to define two functions

```
(defun first-postamble (plist) (format "(c) Donald Duck - %s" (format-time-string "%d %b %Y")))
(defun second-postamble (plist) (format "(c) Daisy Duck - %s" (format-time-string "%d %b %Y")))
```

in my `.emacs` and then use `#+BIND: org-html-postamble first-postamble` in buffers that need the first postamble and correspondingly for the second.

Answer (score 2):

If you're talking about a *file* rather than just a buffer, you can add a [local variables list](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Specifying-File-Variables.html#Specifying-File-Variables).  Either put the following line as the very first line of your file:

```
## -*- org-export-html-postamble: nil -*-
```

or else put the following chunk elsewhere (probably at the very end of the file):

```
## Local Variables:
## org-export-html-postamble: nil
## End:
```

Otherwise, you can temporarily bind the variable by putting this component in the buffer (which would probably be the most org-modey way to do it):

```
#+BIND: org-export-html-postamble nil
```

Based on the following snippet from [the org manual export settings page](http://orgmode.org/manual/Export-settings.html):

*If org-export-allow-bind-keywords is non-nil, Emacs variables can become buffer-local during export by using the BIND keyword. Its syntax is ‘#+BIND: variable value’. This is particularly useful for in-buffer settings that cannot be changed using specific keywords.*

Comment: Hmm, neither of these yields the desired result :(  The buffer local variables are actually set (because I get the security question from emacs), but the postamble is still exported.  I can't tell if the BIND version works.  Probably it does bind the variable, but to no avail because of some org internals.

Comment: Additionally, when using local variables in a special comment (your middle solution) these are not ignored by org-export and thus appear in the resulting html.  This is probably a bug in org?

Comment: Edit: I found the problem.  The variable specified at project scope takes precedence: "Setting :html-postamble in publishing projects will take precedence over this variable."  So, what I want is not possible.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it brought me on the right track.